# Handling discarded events in Server Integration using Webhooks in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

When an event is not added to the event queue, but is instead discarded, What is the way to access discarded event and process it?
How can we access the response to a POST operation after an event gets processed?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an event that was discarded?

Comment: Currently I don't have any example but if the process processing raised events is slow, eventually the queue storing events will be full and not be able to store any new raised event.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no mechanism in Sync Gateway that maintains a history of discarded events - it's just discarded.

This functionality is planned for a future release - tracked as part of https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway/issues/813